# passing a variable declared in one class to another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was trying to set a number in a textfield in one view, that is controlled by one class and make this number appear in a label that is in another view controlled by other class, how do i do it??

Comment: Are you using MVC design? Do you have a model that is separated from the view/controller?

Comment: Read a recent question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11508245/468724

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8383785/468724). There are many question related to this.Try to search.Though they are not exactly what you want but they are similar to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way is NSUserDefault. I don't recommend this but this a way to get data

Saving

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString

[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger

[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double

[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float

[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];

Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString

NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger

NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float

float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```

Comment: I was nearly done typing the exact same answer. I prefaced it with "not necessarily the best, but it works"

Comment: @sunrize920, LOL. That is why i wrote  I don't recommend this. But its a way to solve the problem Gabriel Molter having.

Answer (score 0):

multiple repost like :

[How can I pass a parameter into a view in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924522/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-into-a-view-in-ios)

[iphone Pass String to another .m file in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507906/iphone-pass-string-to-another-m-file-in-project/)

you can also looks `segue` and `protocol delegate`